# What is the difference in nuance between these sentences?

Tags: grammar

> It's probably / certainly going to rain in minutes.
>
> It'll probably / certainly rain in minutes.

Is the 1st one based on something we can see now and the 2nd one based on our personal opinion or knowledge?

Comment: Or, you can simplify things by saying, "I think it's going to rain today," or "I think it'll rain today."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *be* + *going to* can be used to refer to a future event for which there is present evidence. *Will* often describes an intention or, in this case, an opinion, formed more or less at the time of speaking.

That, at least, is the theory, but a native speaker is unlikely to say either of those two. More often a native speaker will say something like *It looks as if it’s going to rain soon* or *It looks as if it’ll rain soon* without much difference in meaning between them.